# WPF: Update foreground with value from dependancy property in ControlTriggers

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following style for a CustomControl in WPF:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BooleanIndicator}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BooleanIndicator}">
                <Border Name="border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="2">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Margin="3">
                        <Label Name="symbol"
                               FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Content="{TemplateBinding Symbol}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="3,0,0,0"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsActive"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{Binding ActiveForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsActive"
                             Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="Gray" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

With a dependency property "ActiveForeground":

```
    public Brush ActiveForeground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ActiveForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActiveForegroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveForegroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ActiveForeground",
            typeof(Brush),
            typeof(BooleanIndicator),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.DarkGreen));
```

However it does not work - the Foreground colour is not updated. If I change the colour in the trigger directly, e.g. `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen" />` it works... What is going on?

Comment: What does your Output window says? i.e. what errors can you see? Have you tired using `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` for your Binding?

Comment: Where do you set the value for `ActiveForeground` Property?

Comment: You must set the `TargetName` of a `Setter` in a `ControlTemplate`: `<Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="symbol" Value="{Binding ActiveForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX No errors.

Comment: @Aakanksha In XAML when defining and instance of the control

Comment: @mm8 That works when targeting individual components. Is there no way to change the actual controls Foreground property? Weird that setting explicitly without a TargetName works, but not with a dep prop. E.g. is there a way to do TargetName = self?

Comment: @geometrikal: Move the trigger to `<Style.Triggers>` instead of `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the `TargetName` of a `Setter` in a `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="symbol" Value="{Binding ActiveForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

If you want to set the `Foreground` property of the control itself, you should use a `Style` trigger:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BooleanIndicator}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BooleanIndicator}">
                <Border Name="border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="2">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Margin="3">
                        <Label Name="symbol"
                               FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Content="{TemplateBinding Symbol}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="3,0,0,0"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{Binding ActiveForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```